# Javascript pass value to asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamic

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainContent_ddlFieldName").live("change", function () {
                 var id = $(this).val();
                 var name = $(this + "option:selected").text();

                 $('#<%= lblValue.ClientID %>').text(name);
                 $('#<%= lblType.ClientID %>').text(id);
             });
         });


<asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true"></asp:Label>



protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string strValue = lblValue.Text;
             string strType = lblType.Text;
        }
```

Im using javascript and Asp.Net to get the value of a dropdownlist and put it in a label.
It actually show the text to the label and when i click a button or event i'm getting its previous value w/c is ""

Can anyone help me with this.

Thx

Comment: var id = $(this).val(); of what..? provide full jqeury

Comment: check my answer use hidden field to get value in code behind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use **hidden field**

aspx page

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hType" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hValue" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Value="" />
<asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button Text="text" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MainContent_ddlFieldName").live("change", function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var name = $(this + "option:selected").text();

            $('#<%= lblValue.ClientID %>').text(name);
            $('#<%= hValue.ClientID %>').val(name);
            $('#<%= lblType.ClientID %>').text(id);
            $('#<%= hType.ClientID %>').val(id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

code behind

```
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //server side code
        string strValue = hValue.Value;
        string strType = hType.Value;


    }
```